# can't show leaderboard, achievements and submit score on achievements

Tags: android

i am unable to show achievements and leader-board and submit scores when i click the buttons here is my code:-

Here the leaderboard and achievements are not opening on clicking the buttons

```
protected static final int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 0;
protected static final int REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS = 0;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.scoreButton)
    {
        counter++;
        giveAchievements(counter);
        textScore.setText(""+counter);

    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.show_achievements)
    {
           startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()),        REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);

    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.show_leaderboard){
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
                getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard)), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
    }
}
```

Here the scores are not submitting to the leaderboard but the game's achievements are unlocking without giving xp or points:-

```
void giveAchievements(int counter)
    {
    if (counter == 7)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
        Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
                getString(R.string.achievement_first_10_clicks));
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(),   getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard), counter*100);
    }
    if (counter == 50)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
        Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
                getString(R.string.achievement_50_clicks));
           Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(),getString(R.string.leader        board_leaderboard), counter*100);
    } if (counter == 100)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.achievement_100_clicks));
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(),    getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard), counter*100);
    } if (counter == 7)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.achievement_250_clicks));
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), "CgkI-eXOwZsFEAIQBg", counter*100);
    } if (counter == 500)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.achievement_500_clicks));
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard), counter*100);
    } if (counter == 1000)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.achievement_1000_clicks));
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard), counter*100);
    } if (counter == 1500)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.achievement_1500_clicks));
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard), counter*100);
    } if (counter == 3000)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.achievement_3000_clicks));
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard), counter*100);
    } if (counter == 5000)
    {   if(getApiClient().isConnected())
    Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.achievement_5000_clicks));
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_leaderboard), counter*100);
    }
    }
```

Here is the screenshot achievements is stuck at 10000
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SVzR.png)

Comment: u need add logs and check counter value.. and more have you set onclick listeners

Comment: @sush thanks for replying wait i will edit the question!

Comment: @shush ya i just checked i didnt declared the onclick listener now it is working but im not seeing earned xp on the achievements block.

Comment: @shush and also im not seeing achievements and leaderboard on my google play app.